Вопрос про обновление переменной-состояния после выхода из обработчика события
В документации к Реакт написано: ‟React ожидает, пока не будет выполнен весь код в обработчиках событий, прежде чем обрабатывать ваши обновления состояния”. То есть переменная-состояние изменится тогда, когда завершится функция-обработчик, внутри которой изменяется состояние. Но если я напишу компонент, где в функции-обработчике после изменения состояния я поставлю задержку, то всё-равно при нажатии на кнопку с функцией-обработчиком события изменение состояния произойдёт сразу же, то есть ещё до выполнения задержки и выполнения кода до конца в функции-обработчике. Вот код компонента:
function Component() {
  let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  async function handleClick(){ 
    setNumber(number + 1);
    await delay(1000);
    console.log("hello");
  }

  return (<div style={{background: "gray", padding: "20px", border: "1px solid black"}}>
    <div>Number: {number}</div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button> 
  </div>
); 
}

function delay(time){ //моя функция для задержки
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(); 
  }, time)})
}


Твой await delay(1000); не является задержкой. Она "задерживает" только выполнение console.log("hello"); Замени на тот же alert('Стоп') - это действительно "не даст" стейту измениться.

Изменение состояния в React происходит асинхронно, но обновление интерфейса не ждет завершения всех асинхронных операций в функции-обработчике.
В вашем случае, хотя задержка в функции handleClick есть, изменение состояния setNumber(number + 1) выполняется сразу, не дожидаясь окончания задержки. Думаю, что это нормально для React.
